# I cant call method in same class

Tags: php

When i call method  `validate()` i get this mistake Parse

> **error:** syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting T_FUNCTION in \04Task.php on line 205

```
    class RegexValidationRule extends ValidationRule {
    public $regex;
    public $result;

    public function validate() {
        $this->result = preg_match( $this->regex, $this->field->get_value() );
    }

}

class ValidEmailValidationRule extends RegexValidationRule {
    protected $regex = "^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$";

    $this->validate();
}
```

Comment: You're having syntax issues, take a close look at the error: "Parse error: SYNTAX error, unexpected ...". I hope it helps :)

Comment: Also, $regex is required be public in ValidEmailValidationRule, as it's public in its parent

Comment: It'd be great if you can tell us what's on or which line is `line 205`.

Comment: $this->validate() is floating in the middle of the class definition, like a baby floating in the vacuum of space...

Comment: Is this some existing Validation Library or are you creating your own? Should `$this->validate();` be  `public function validate() { parent::validate(); }`? There is an issue with property $regex. It generates an error about visibility? Do you have PHP error handling switched on?

Answer (score 0):

```
class ValidEmailValidationRule extends RegexValidationRule {
    protected $regex = "^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$";

    public function __construct() {
         $this->validate();
    }
}
```

You can't be statements in the middle of a class definition like that, they have to be called inside functions.